# Calling external js function from Angular 5 not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I called hello function from ts file but I got error like hello is not defined.

**hello.js**

```
function hello() {
    alert("Hello.......!");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="./assets/js/hello.js"></script>
```

**component.ts**

```
declare var hello: any;

// calling on load
let result = hello();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You do not need to declare it again in your ts.

Comment: then how can i get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Include your JS file in angular-cli.json file under `scripts` array

```
"scripts": [

]
```

make sure to put the correct relative URL. And then you can simply use it in your `ts` file. Make sure to restart `ng serve` if you are using it.